# Redirect wrong url with extension to non extension

Tags: iis, redirect

Our product URL works this way:
//name.com/clientname/
One of our new clients by mistake printed out the URL on cards this way:
//name.com/clientname.org
Now i want to redirect the wrong one(second) to the correct one(without.org)
Every solution I found was about hiding the extension 
I don’t want to hide it,I want to redirect it to correct one in IIS

Comment: "Every solution I found was about hiding the extension". That's impossible. Using IIS URL Rewrite, what you need is the simplest redirection, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module#creating-a-redirect-rule

Answer (score 0):

As Lex Li says, we could use IIS url rewrite to achieve your requirement.

You could firstly install it from below url:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then I suggest you could add below url inside the web.config.

```
            <rule name="ExtensionRewrtie">
                <match url="clientname.org" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://name.com/clientname" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```